# two optional with a starting sign

Tags: regex

**`hello(?:-(?:1(one))?(?:2(two))?)?-`**

i accept those patterns

```
hello-
hello-1one-
hello-2two-
hello-1one2two-
```

my problem is this pattern

```
hello--
```

is accepted too and i want to make `?:-` to be required when `1one` or `2two` exists only

how to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use alternatives rather than making each item optional.

```
hello-(?:(?:1one|2two|1one2two)-)?
```